# How to check generic type in generic method

Tags: java, generics

I need something like this (C# sample)  in Java

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Method<String>();
        }

        static void Method<T>()
        {
            Type typeT = typeof(T);
            Type typeString = typeof(String);
            if (typeT == typeString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is String");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have generic method and need check type T in method.

```
protected <T> MyClass<T> myMethod(MyClass<T> myObj){
   // if  T is string do ..., else do ... 
}
```

Comment: You can't, basically. Search for "type erasure"

Comment: You can use `if (myObj instanceof String)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an additional parameter of type `Class<T>`, because after type erasure the generic information will be erased. However, having a `Class<T>` will allow you to access (meta) information about `T` at Runtime:

```
protected <T> MyClass<T> myMethod(MyClass<T> myObj, Class<T> clazz) {
   if (clazz == String.class) { ... } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `typeof(T);` because T is undefined/not-known at runtime.

> In Java, Generics will not exist at **Runtime**, it works on concept called erasure.

[Docs:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.

You can solve this by using the `instanceof` operator on the  parameter

i.e. `myObj instanceof String`

or also answer suggested by @kocko